# height not divisible by 2 (176x99)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, libx264

I am trying to convert a .avi file into a .mp4 one using FFMPEG using the libx264 codec.

This is the command I am running:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 19 -strict experimental filenameAvi.mp4
```

I sometimes get the following error:

```
[libx264 @ 0x85b460] height not divisible by 2 (176x99)
```

I used the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847674/ffmpeg-libx264-height-not-divisible-by-2

and modified the command accordingly as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.avi -c:v libx264 -vf "scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2" -crf 19 -strict experimental filenameAvi.mp4
```

For the same file what now happens is it hangs up after a couple of frames. I have not much idea about ffmpeg, kindly suggest how to solve this.
[image: Fscreenshot]

Comment: Upgrade to 4.0 and check.

Comment: i am unable to find a suitable link for upgrading ffmpeg to 4.0 on  ubuntu 16.04, could you please point one?

Comment: Get a static build from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: Hi, sorry for replying late. After upgrading to 4.0 it is working fine.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I do have same problem.

Step1: change resolution of your .avi file

```
ffmpeg -i filename.avi -vf "scale=176:98" filename1.avi
```

Step2: convert .avi to .mp4

```
ffmpeg -i filename1.avi filename.mp4
```

That works for me